# CSS animation not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css-animations, internet-explorer-11

I inherit a website from another programmer and I am facing an issue. The website has a css animation that works perfect in Chrome and Mozilla but doesn't work in Internet Exporer 11 (maybe previous versions as well). The background is just plain white with no background image animation.

I guess it is something with the prefixes of the animation CSS but I can't make it work

Can anyone help me?

Link: http://presentamivuelo.com/ver-view/TIiY1wLt

Answer (score 0):

Add `IE=edge` to your `X-UA` meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

Your site takes over 3 minutes to load with a 4 Mb/s connection (in all browsers)... the target is 3 seconds.

See http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed for some tips (compress your slideshow images, resource cache, etc.) and http://modern.ie/report

You may also like to look up what the bounce rate for similar sites is at http://alexa.com. Usually your hosting provider is able to provide you with some basic site statistics. I would expect that the site has a very high bounce rate and a short visitation time.

Honestly.... it's a dogs breakfast there.... Instead of third-party hosting, you should also consider dedicated hosting with your own server instance.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the IE=edge but still the same issue, and the strange is that there is no error at all anywhere in the Developer Tools. Also, thanks for the suggestions about the optmization of the webpage, for sure I will take a look into that after I fix the IE issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I'm suspecting the issue may have been the same as the one posted here: [Background-image in keyframe does not display in Firefox or Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994521/background-image-in-keyframe-does-not-display-in-firefox-or-internet-explorer)

If anyone else is here for the same reason, you cannot animate the background-image as it is a non-animatable property https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-image