# Why does my animation not work in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations, linear-gradients

I have some code that works perfectly in Chrome but it doesn't work in Firefox
I want my logo image shine in my website. Code runs in Chrome but I don't know why it doesn't work in Firefox.

```
.shine-me {
    width:100%; /*Make sure the animation is over the whole element*/
    -webkit-animation-name: ShineAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.12,.89,.98,.47);
    animation:ShineAnimation 5s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.12,.89,.98,.47);
}
@-webkit-keyframes ShineAnimation{
    from {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(
            top left,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 45%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 48%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 50%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 52%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 57%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
        );
        background-position:-250px -250px;
        background-size: 600px 600px
    }
    to {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:250px 250px;
    }
}

@keyframes ShineAnimation{
    from {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-image:linear-gradient(
            top left,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 45%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 48%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 50%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 52%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 57%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
        );
        background-position:-250px -250px;
        background-size: 600px 600px
    }
    to {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:250px 250px;
    }
}
p
{
    background-color:#c0c0c0;
    padding:15px;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If yes, consider marking it as accepted (click the hollow tick mark below the voting buttons).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in Firefox because of two reasons:

- You are using the old WebKit specific linear gradient syntax inside the `@keyframes` rule. The new syntax [must have the `to` keyword before the sides](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients) (like `to top left`).
- Firefox doesn't support declaring the `background-image` within `@keyframes` unlike browsers that use WebKit. The reason is described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994521/background-image-in-keyframe-does-not-display-in-firefox-or-internet-explorer/36005661#36005661). Move the `background-image` properties that are applied within the `0%` frame to the base selector and animate just `background-position`.

```css
.shine-me {
  width: 100%;  /*Make sure the animation is over the whole element*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 45%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 48%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 57%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
  background-position: -250px -250px;
  background-size: 600px 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: ShineAnimation 5s infinite cubic-bezier(.12, .89, .98, .47);
  animation: ShineAnimation 5s infinite cubic-bezier(.12, .89, .98, .47);
}
@-webkit-keyframes ShineAnimation {
  from {
    background-position: -250px -250px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 500px 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes ShineAnimation {
  from {
    background-position: -250px -250px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 500px 0px; /* increase the X position as required */
  }
}
p {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p class='shine-me'>Some text</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will also need to add following css :

```css
-moz-animation:ShineAnimation 5s infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.12,.89,.98,.47); 


@-moz-keyframes ShineAnimation{
    from {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(
            top left,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 45%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 48%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 50%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 52%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 57%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
        );
        background-position:-250px -250px;
        background-size: 600px 600px
    }
    to {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:250px 250px;
    }
}
```

Comment: `-moz-` prefix is not required for animations in Firefox since v16. You are either using a very old version of FF (or) didn't bother testing before posting an answer.