# Is it possible to do this animation with pure CSS3 without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

This is a very simple background color change animation. Is it possible to do that using pure CSS3?

```js
var square = document.querySelector('.square');
var percentYellow = 0;
function changeBackground(){
 percentYellow = percentYellow + 10;
 square.style.background = 'linear-gradient(90deg, yellow '+percentYellow+'%, blue 0)';
 if(percentYellow<=100){
  setTimeout(changeBackground,200);
 }
}
changeBackground();
```

```css
 .square{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 0%, blue 0);
  border:1px solid;
 }
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want it to go in steps, like the example, or fluid?

Comment: @randy fluid may be better.

Comment: Could anyone explain why this is downvoted? Is there a way for me to see if this is flagged for a reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can animate the `background-position`:

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 50%, blue 0);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: slideBG 2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes slideBG {
  0% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Or, as @Harry pointed out, you can use `steps()` to maintain the "stepped" transition that your javascript version produces:

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 50%, blue 0);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: slideBG 2s steps(10, end) forwards;
}
@keyframes slideBG {
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: This is the best option in my opinion. Using `steps()` function (`steps(10,end)`) instead of linear would make it closer to the demo in question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You can make the `.square` element blue, and `::after` pseudo-element yellow, and then animate the width of `::after`:

```css
@keyframes animation {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.square::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: animation 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [use css animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) and you need to set `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to retain the final animation style otherwise it will rollback to the initial style.

> ***animation-fill-mode: forwards*** -The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution.(Taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode))

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 0%, blue 0);
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: anim 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* retain the css applied by animation */
}
@keyframes anim {
  0% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 0%, blue 0);  }
  10% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 10%, blue 0);  }
  20% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 20%, blue 0);  }
  30% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 30%, blue 0);  }
  40% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 40%, blue 0);  }
  50% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 50%, blue 0);  }
  60% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 60%, blue 0);  }
  70% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 70%, blue 0);  }
  80% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 80%, blue 0);  }
  90% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 90%, blue 0);  }
  100% {    background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 100%, blue 0);  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Just a word of caution - Don't use `background` (with gradients or images) inside keyframes. Firefox will ignore them. This snippet won't work in it. You can see more details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994521/background-image-in-keyframe-does-not-display-in-firefox-or-internet-explorer/36005661#36005661

Comment: Apart form the issue mentioned by Harry, this solution is kind of clumsy. Just imagine you have  100 or more keyframes instead of 10 here...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```css
.contain{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  background-color:blue;
  position:relative;
  }

.overcontain{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  animation:anime 2s linear;
  position:absolute;
  }

@keyframes anime{
  0%{width:0%;}
  100%{width:100%;}
  }
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="overcontain"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't create other empty elements when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with CSS only

```
.square{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 0%, blue 0);
    border:1px solid;
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% { background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 0%, blue 0); }
  10% { background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 10%, blue 0); }
  20% { background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 20%, blue 0); }
  /* and so on ... */
  100% { background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 100%, blue 0); }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyMYWz?editors=1100#anon-signup

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Others has beaten me and answered while I was typing this, but since I included a link to a documentation that nobody else mentioned I'm going to post this anyway.

---

You can create animations using only CSS3 with the `@keyframes` rules and `animation-*` properties.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp for reference.

Here is a little snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.square{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 0%, blue 0%);
    border:1px solid;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   {background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 0%, blue 0%)}
    25%  {background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 25%, blue 0%)}
    50%  {background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 50%, blue 0%)}
    75%  {background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 75%, blue 0%)}
    100% {background:linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 100%, blue 0%)}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="square"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** There is a mess regarding vendors with these properties/rules and due that I couldn't get it working (tried it on Firefox 44). And to keep it simple I used only the default sintax. I hope it can shed some light on this at least.

**Edit:** Possibly I couldn't get it working due the fact mentioned in comments here.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set how many steps you want to realize.

```css
        .square{
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            background:blue;
            border:1px solid;
            position: relative;
        }
        .square:before{
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            background: yellow;
            display:block;
            left: 0;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            right: 100%;
            -webkit-animation: play 2s steps(10);
            -moz-animation: play 2s steps(10);
             -ms-animation: play 2s steps(10);
              -o-animation: play 2s steps(10);
                 animation: play 2s steps(10);
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes play {
           from { right: 100%; }
             to { right: 0px; }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes play {
           from { right: 100%; }
             to { right: 0px; }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes play {
           from { right: 100%; }
             to { right: 0px; }
        }

        @-o-keyframes play {
           from { right: 100%; }
             to { right: 0px; }
        }
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```