# Is it possible to animate background: linear-gradient using CSS 3 Animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know if it is possible to animate using CSS Animations a property

`background: linear-gradient()`

I am trying the following code (only valid for Chrome) and I cannot achieve the desired result.

If no possible with CSS Animations, can be solved using CSS Transitions, if yes could you please provide an example? Thanks.

```css
#target {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #18f0b8, #18a2f0, #db5640);
  background-size: 600% 600%;
  animation: Gradient 8s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #18f0b8, #18a2f0, #db5640);
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #18f0b8, #18a2f0, #ffffff);
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Gradients are images and so no, you can't. Reason is described in my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994521/background-image-in-keyframe-does-not-display-in-firefox-or-internet-explorer/36005661#36005661

Comment: Here, You may relay on background-size and integrate both bg at once. example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YpQZGP/

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry I did not notice this question was already answered :)